# Getting Error building time : The "TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript

The "**TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive**" task could not be loaded from the assembly F:_Websites\AfricaAccess\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.1\build\..\tools\net45\TypeScript.Tasks.dll.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Comment: update typescript vs2015

Answer (score 0):

After updating vs2015 typescript error gone.